# CPU usage dips after pruning completed apply_async tasks

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have an application which reads in millions of data points from a file, transforms each data point into data structure A, filters duplicates using a `toString` function and then transforms data structure A into a data structure B.  In addition, since the number of data points is large and data structure B takes less memory than data structure A, I've written the loops such that generation of the data structure B is as lazy as possible.  To ensure that this process runs quickly, I have implemented a pair of `multiprocessing.Pool` objects which parallelize both the generation of data structures A and B, respectively.

Initially, I used `imap_unordered` to lazily create instances of data structure A from the input file and then submitted A to B transformations via `apply_async`.  However, after about 10,000 data points or so, I would receive memory errors complaining that my shared memory requests were not able to be allocated.  I attributed this to a buildup of `AsyncResult` objects which were holding on to the data structure B results, and therefore I implemented a pruning procedure that would grab the result from the `AsyncResult` and remove the reference.  However, whenever I call this pruning procedure, the CPU usage drops from 100% per CPU to ~20% per CPU and never recovers.  Can I stop this CPU drop from happening, or is there a better way of going about this?  Below is a simplified version of my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

p = mp.Pool(4) #Handles generation of structureA
q = mp.Pool(32) #Handles generation of structureB
n = 0 #Counter for invoking pruning
structureBs = [] #List of final output structures
Aresults = [] #List of AsyncResult objects
Astrings = set() #Set of strings for removing duplicates

for structureA in p.imap_unordered(generateStructA, readFile(inputFile)):
    Astring = structureA.toString()
    if Astring not in Astrings:
        Astrings.add(Astring)
        Aresults.append(q.apply_async(generateStructB, (structureA, )))
        n += 1
        if n % 1000 == 0:
            for res in Aresults:
                if res.ready():
                    structureB = res.get()
                    structureBs.append(structureB)
                    Aresults.remove(res)

#Catch any B generation tasks that weren't finished
for res in Aresults:
    structureB = res.get()
    structureBs.append(structureB)
```

**UPDATE:** I decided to transform the pruning loop into a callback function, which shortened the code significantly:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

p = mp.Pool(4) #Handles generation of structureA
q = mp.Pool(32) #Handles generation of structureB
structureBs = [] #List of final output structures
Astrings = set() #Set of strings for removing duplicates

def callback(result):
    structureBs.append(result)

for structureA in p.imap_unordered(generateStructA, readFile(inputFile)):
    Astring = structureA.toString()
    if Astring not in Astrings:
        Astrings.add(Astring)
        q.apply_async(generateStructB, (structureA, ), callback=callback)
```

However, I still found that the CPU usage was dropping significantly.  What this means is that the slowdown was likely due to latency in the parent process to querying the results of the child processes.  I was able to somewhat resolve the issue by transforming my `mp.Pool` objects into `mp.pool.ThreadPool` objects, thus changing my script from a multiprocessing task to a multithreaded task.  Doing this eliminates the necessity of copying memory from child to parent as threads share the same memory.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might try is to not use `apply_async` for creating the `StructB` instances but instead use a second `imap_unordered` call. Note that when using `imap_unordered`, best performance is achieved using an appropriate *chunksize* argument as is done in the code below. The function `compute_chunksize` is computing a value based on the size of the iterable being passed to `imap_unordered` and the pool size much in the same way a value would be computed if you were using `map` without specifying an explicit  *chunksize* argument. This may not be the best choice for you as a larger *chunksize* value requires more memory. Also note that when you use `apply_async`, you have no ability to "chunk" the requests and so for large iterables this would be far less efficient than using `imap_unordered` with a *chunksize* argument.

For best memory utilization function `readfile` should be a generator function or return a generator expression instead of returning, for example, a list of all the data points (I can't tell what it does because you have not posted the code).

```py
import multiprocessing as mp


# Best estimate of the number of data points:
NUMBER_DATA_POINTS = 3_000_000

# Best estimate of the number of distinct StructA instances
# generated:
NUMBER_STRUCT_A = 1_000_000

def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

def generate_strings():
    Astrings = set() #Set of strings for removing duplicates

    with mp.Pool(4) as pool: #Handles generation of structureA
        chunksize = compute_chunksize(NUMBER_DATA_POINTS, 4)
        for structureA in pool.imap_unordered(
                            generateStructA,
                            readFile(inputFile),
                            chunksize=chunksize
                            ):
            Astring = structureA.toString()
            if Astring not in Astrings:
                Astrings.add(Astring)
                yield structureA

def generate_structures():
    with mp.Pool(32) as pool: #Handles generation of structureB
        chunksize = compute_chunksize(NUMBER_STRUCT_A, 32)
        return list(
            pool.imap_unordered(
                generateStructB,
                generate_strings(),
                chunksize=chunksize
                )
            )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    structureBs = generate_structures()
```